# Open messenger chatbot webview extension in Chrome

Tags: bots, botframework, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I am trying to access the camera inside my webview extension that works perfectly fine on Google Chrome when I open it as a website separately. I have my bot made using Microsoft Bot Framework and when I try the bot on Messenger it seems that messenger pops open its own browser of some sort and that doesnt allow my camera. Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks for your help in advance